# Android divisions always results in 0

Tags: java, android, math, double, integer-division

Please check the below android code

```
private void preMealChartCreator(int numberOfPreMealLow, int numberOfPreMealNormal, int numberOfPreMealHigh, int totalReadings) {

        Log.d("OverViewFragment","chart_low: "+numberOfPreMealLow+" chart_normalssss: "+numberOfPreMealNormal+" chart_high: "+numberOfPreMealHigh+" chart_total: "+totalReadings);
        int preMealLowPercentage = (int)((numberOfPreMealLow/totalReadings)*100);
        double preMealNormalPercentage = (double)((numberOfPreMealNormal/totalReadings)*100);
        int preMealHighPercentage = (int)((numberOfPreMealHigh/totalReadings)*100);

        Log.d("OverViewFragment","chart_low: "+"low_percentage: "+preMealLowPercentage+" normal_percentage: "+preMealNormalPercentage+ "high_percentage: "+preMealHighPercentage);
        Log.d("OverViewFragment","chart_low: "+ " chart_normalssss: "+numberOfPreMealNormal+ " chart_total: " +totalReadings+" normal_manual: "+ (1/5)*100);


        lowBarView.set(Color.GRAY, preMealLowPercentage);
        normalBarView.set(Color.GREEN, (int)preMealNormalPercentage);
        highBarView.set(Color.YELLOW, preMealHighPercentage);
        verHighBarView.set(Color.RED, 6);

        lowTextView.setText(getPercentage(preMealLowPercentage));
        normalTextView.setText(getPercentage((int)preMealNormalPercentage));
        highTextView.setText(getPercentage(preMealHighPercentage));
        veryHighTextView.setText(getPercentage(6));

    }
```

No matter what I do, my percentrages are always 0. I wanted to check whether anything is `null` or 0, so I printed the log, everything fine. Log is below

```
01-13 18:50:08.647 9232-9232/xx.com.au.xxD/OverViewFragment: chart_low: 0 chart_normalssss: 1 chart_high: 2 chart_total: 5
01-13 18:50:08.647 9232-9232/xx.com.au.xxD/OverViewFragment: chart_low: low_percentage: 0 normal_percentage: 0.0high_percentage: 0
01-13 18:50:08.647 9232-9232/xx.com.au.xxD/OverViewFragment: chart_low:  chart_normalssss: 1 chart_total: 5 normal_manual: 0
```

I even tried manually converting to `double` and then hard coding values, nothi8ng worked. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Cast one of variables to `float` before division:

`int preMealLowPercentage = (int)((numberOfPreMealLow/(float)totalReadings)*100);`

Because otherwise you're operating with integers.

Or you could simply move `*100` like:

`int preMealLowPercentage = (int)((numberOfPreMealLow*100/totalReadings));`